# How to set JDBC-specific properties in PySpark when connecting to Trino using Trino's JDBC

Tags: python, pyspark, jdbc, trino

I'm trying to connect PySpark to Trino using Trino's JDBC driver. The connection works as expected in DBeaver, where I set the SSLVerification property = NONE to bypass the SSL check.

However, when I try to connect to Trino from PySpark, I get an error stating that I cannot set SSLVerification as a parameter. It seems that SSLVerification is a Trino JDBC-specific property, and PySpark does not support this property itself.

I was wondering if there's a way to set JDBC-specific properties in PySpark when creating a connection. Any guidance or workaround would be highly appreciated.

**Python code**

```py
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", trino_jdbc_driver_path)
    .master("local")
    .appName("Test Write")
    .getOrCreate()
)

query_test = """SELECT 1"""
test_df = (
    spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", trino_url)
    .option("driver", trino_driver)
    .option("dbtable", query_test)
    .option("user", trino_user)
    .option("password", trino_password)
    .option("SSLVerification", "NONE")
    .load()
)
```

**Working DBeaver properties**: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDjuJ.png)

**Pyspark version**: 3.0.0

**Trino JDBC Driver**: trino-jdbc-380.jar

So far, I have tried the following approaches:

1. Updating to the latest Trino JDBC driver.
2. Setting .option("SSL", "false") in PySpark.